# What does 「そのせい」 mean?

Tags: translation, words

Found a sentence:

> 屋上に来てしまったのも**そのせい**

What does そのせい mean in that sentence?

Answer (score 6):

~せい　marks the reason for something, basically means "Because of ..."

その　means "that"

Combining these the whole sentence means:

Ending up on the rooftop was because of that too.

Comment: +1, additionally  note that せい is usually used for the reason for something undesirable.